# Customizing Search bar

Tags: css, search

I want to make the search bar longer and higher. Lining up with the end of the body (width) and menu (heighth). I looked at other tutorials and questions but I am missing something.

CSS

```
form input[type="text"] {
    height: 45px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<form name="catsearchform60238" method="post" action="/Default.aspx?SiteSearchID=2433&PageID=/search.html">
    <div class="cat_textbox">
        <input type="text" value="text field"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input> 
</form>
```

Comment: http://foyermakeover.businesscatalyst.com/index.html

Comment: The above works fine..

Answer (score 0):

Using `display: block;` is probably what you are looking for.

```
form input[type="text"] {
    display: block;
    height: 45px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    float: left;
}
```